# Jquery Chrome extension help?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Chrome extensions where you can drag and drop links and it'll bookmark it in the extension. I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C8yAa/2/) from a stackoverflow thread, it does what I want it to but the only problem is that I want it to make a new element with the link and not replace the old link. Can someone point me to the right direction. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I modified that fiddle to match your request. Each dropped link now creates a new LI element within a UL. I suggest you read up on the Chrome Bookmark API if you haven't already, and I commented the fiddle to show locations where you would use API functions. If you want to remember which bookmarks the user has created through the extension, you may want to set up localStorage as well to save the ID of the created bookmark.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArkahnX/jwsdm/5/

LocalStorage: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/html5_local_storage.htm

Chrome Bookmarks API:http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html

Comment: This is awesome thanks alot for the help. The only problem is that it turns out that you can't click inside the document page without the extension auto closing. I was trying to find a solution for this and it turns out there isn't one. I had to stop making this extension.

Comment: @Nick You could maybe have an overlay on the top of the screen where the user could drop the item and have the extension store that